# Plotting a graph with lines one factor and data points only for another factor in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have made the following with `ggplot2`, using the code below:

[image: graph]

```
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=Characteristic, y=Rating, group=Factor, colour=Factor)) +
geom_point() +
geom_line()+
ylim(0,10)+
xlab("Characteristics") + theme(text = element_text(size=20))
```

I only want to use lines to connect data points for two of the Factors (A-H), the other factors just need the data points (no lines connecting). 
How can I do this?

My data is in this form:

```
     Factor Characteristic Rating
1       A             OA      7
2       B             OA      6
3       C             OA      5
4       D             OA      4
5       E             OA      5
6       F             OA      6
7       G             OA      7
8       H             OA      1
9       A             HS      7
10      B             HS      2
11      C             HS      5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an identifier into your data frame with `ifelse`, and filter your data with `dplyr`:

```
d$lc <- ifelse(d$Factor %in% c("A", "H"), "line", "point")

ggplot(data=d, aes(x=Characteristic, y=Rating, group=Factor, colour=Factor)) +
geom_point() +
geom_line(data=filter(d, d$lc == "line"), aes(x=Characteristic, y=Rating, group=Factor, colour=Factor))
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Perhaps I should make this a separate question, but how could I reorder the legend?

It is currently alphabetical - but is there a way to reorder the legend based on the ratings for factor "HS"? (i.e. G, A, H, ...etc. would be the order of the legend)

Comment: @lily23  Modify the sequence of `levels` with function `factor`.

Comment: Thanks @Pascal - here is what I used to make that work:
    d$Factor <- factor(d$Factor, levels=c("G", "A", "H", "F", "C", "D","B" ,"E"),labels=c("G", "A", "H", "F", "C", "D","B" ,"E"))